# Izpack can not find class of custom action defined for InstallPanel

Tags: izpack, izpanel

I use 5.0.0-rc4 as izpack version and `izpack-installer` artifact exists as a dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-installer</artifactId>
    <version>${izpack.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have defined a custom action `DeletePreviousInstallationAction` for `InstallPanel`.

InstallPanel definition is included in install.xml as below.

```
<panels>
    <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>                
    <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="panelUserInput"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel">
        <actions>
            <action stage="preconstruct" classname="com.x.y.z.w.DeletePreviousInstallationAction" />
        </actions>
    </panel>
    <panel classname="ProcessPanel"/>
    <panel classname="SimpleFinishPanel"/>
</panels>
```

`DeletePreviousInstallationAction` code:

```
package com.x.y.z.w;

import com.izforge.izpack.api.data.InstallData;
import com.izforge.izpack.api.data.PanelActionConfiguration;
import com.izforge.izpack.api.handler.AbstractUIHandler;
import com.izforge.izpack.data.PanelAction;

public class DeletePreviousInstallationAction implements PanelAction {

    @Override
    public void executeAction(InstallData id, AbstractUIHandler auih) {

        System.out.println("Intall path: " + id.getInstallPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(PanelActionConfiguration pac) {
    }
}
```

When I try to build setup project, I get **Failure: Class 'com.x.y.z.w.DeletePreviousInstallationAction' not found.** Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing it during compilation, it has to be added in "jar" section to install xml of izpack e.g.:

```
<jar src="@{jmx4ant:jmx4ant:jar}" stage="both" />
```